# How to pivot a date column into multiple columns by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following table that displays the hours that employees have worked in an assigned job per day.

```
   emp_num   |  job   |      initial_date     |  worked_hours
  ----------  --------  ---------------------  -------------
    100001     VESS_10   2019-01-01 06:00:00         2
    100001     VESS_20   2019-01-01 08:00:00         1 
    100001     VESS_30   2019-01-02 06:00:00         1
    100002     VESS_20   2019-01-02 08:00:00         2 
    100002     VESS_20   2019-01-03 10:00:00         2
    100003     VESS_30   2019-01-01 11:00:00         1
```

I would like to display the following result:

```
   emp_num   |  job   |      2019-01-01    |    2019-01-02      |    2019-01-03   |  worked_hours
  ----------  --------  -------------------   ---------------   ------------------  ------------
    100001     VESS_10   2019-01-01 06:00:00     NULL                  NULL             2
    100001     VESS_20   2019-01-01 08:00:00     NULL                  NULL             1
    100001     VESS_30          NULL          2019-01-02 06:00:00      NULL             1
    100002     VESS_20          NULL          2019-01-02 08:00:00      NULL             2
    100002     VESS_20          NULL             NULL              2019-01-03 10:00:00  2
    100003     VESS_30   2019-01-01 11:00:00     NULL                  NULL             1
```

What I tried was to pivot the table with the following query:

```
select * from 
    (
     select emp_num, job, initial_date worked_hours
     from transactions
     where initial_date between '2019-04-21 00:00:00' and '2019-04-27 23:59:59'
)
as hours_table
pivot (
    sum(worked_hours)
    for initial_date in (['my problem comes here'])])
)
```

The problem with the code from above is that in the `for` statement I want to declare the dates in 7 columns because they represent each day of the week, however, I do not know how to classify each row based on the date and then assign it in the correct column.

Any help, comment or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT B.emp_num,B.initial_date,B.Date_Only,B.job,
    (
        SELECT SUM(worked_hours) 
        FROM transactions 
        WHERE emp_num = B.emp_num AND  job = B.job
    ) worked_hours
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT emp_num,job,initial_date,worked_hours,CAST(initial_date AS DATE) Date_Only 
        FROM transactions
    )B
    WHERE initial_date between '2018-12-30 00:00:00' and '2019-01-05 23:59:59'
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(initial_date)
    FOR Date_Only IN ([2019-01-01],[2019-01-02],[2019-01-03])
)PVT
```

Comment: How would you adjust the dates automatically from the `For Date_Only`? That is, what if I want to adjust the days for the next week without the need to type each day separately?

Comment: You can set date range in the filter. For you also need to define the FOR Date_Only IN (......) accordingly. If more clarification required, please tell me.

Comment: I noticed there is a lose of working hour for "100002/VESS_20" and edited the code so that it shows 4 hours where as it was showing 2 hours with earlier code.